# Run Macro in more than 1 workbook at the same time

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2007. When I start the Macro in the workbook, I cannot do any other work in Excel. I have to wait till the Macro finishes.

Is it possible to run multiple macro in multiple workbooks at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you have two separate workbooks, and you'd like to be able to work on 1, while running macro on the other.

This can be achieved by running two separate instances of excel, and opening the workbook in each.
Note, if you just double click a xls, it will open in the same running instance.

So you need to actually open a new instance which will be black and go file->open and navigate to your desired workbook (I think drag and drop works too)>

Comment: Thanks. Now I can run 12 Macros in 12 separate workbooks at a time.